# user list is coming empty in android

Tags: android, json

Hi in the below code user list is giving empty list from the server while parsing JSON data from the server. once the user list is populated I am setting to spinner adapter .but list itself empty. inside of the type object, I have other user's objects. users list is empty

Can anyone help me where I did the mistake?

below is my java code and logs also attached.

```
String response1 = new Gson().toJson(response.body());

ArrayList<Users> userList = new ArrayList<>();

JSONObject jsonobj = null;
JSONObject object = null;
JSONObject user = null;
try {
    jsonobj = new JSONObject(response1);
    JSONObject jsonobj1 = new JSONObject();
    jsonobj1 = jsonobj.getJSONObject("result");
    JSONObject jsonobj2 = new JSONObject();
    jsonobj2 = jsonobj1.getJSONObject("describe");

    JSONArray values = jsonobj2.getJSONArray("fields");

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject fields = values.getJSONObject(i);

        String names = fields.getString("name");
        // String name = animal.getString("name");
        if (names.equals("assigned_user_id")) {
            JSONObject type = null;

            type = fields.getJSONObject("type");
            Log.i("type", ":" + type);

            JSONObject users = null;

            String own_name = type.getString("name");
            Log.i("own_name", ":" + own_name);
            if (own_name.equals("owner")) {
                users = type.getJSONObject("users");
                for (int j = 0; j < users.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject user_list = users.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(j));
                    Log.i("users", ":" + users);
                    Iterator<String> keys = user_list.keys();

                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
                        String key = keys.next();
                        String value1 = null;
                        try {
                            value1 = user.getString(key);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Users users1 = new Users(key, value1);
                        userList.add(users1);
                        ArrayAdapter<Users> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Users>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, userList);
                        spinneraccountManager.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
    //JSONObject users = animal.getJSONObject("users");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Logs:

```
I/type: :{"name":"owner","users":{}}
I/own_name: :owner
I/type: :{"name":"owner","users":{}}
I/own_name: :owner
```

Comment: if user list you are receiving is empty from server, there is no mistake from your side. If you get any exception while taking the values then you have a problem.

Comment: Can you post your JSON data?

Comment: @sanjeev not from server

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh see my edit post

Comment: @jyothidadi Your json response seems to be wrong. If you have to take the values as an array you should create a json array. I'd suggest to go for a change in the backend side.

Comment: @sanjeev is right, you are receiving empty user field from server, please run once your url on postman

Comment: @sanjeev values are there in server

Comment: This is a suggestion not an answer. You can use Gson for your json parsing.

Comment: @ErginErsoy let me know small help requied

Comment: @ErginErsoy smart. That's why it's in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @jyothidadi it needs to be `users": [ "19x1": "Admin Administrator", "19x5": "Ganeshprasad S", "19x6": "Balaji RR", "19x7": "Kiran Thadimarri" ]`

Comment: @sanjeev it was irrelevant with question thats why i explained. :)

Comment: @ErginErsoy Can't use wrong to make wrong right.

Comment: @sanjeev delete the comment

Comment: @jyothidadi please update your question json response. I will generate pojo classes and post an answer how you can parse with Gson.

Comment: @sanjeev yes like you didn't here.

Comment: @jyothidadi, this is the separate thread and you were asking this on another thread

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong here

```
users = type.getJSONObject("users");
```

if `users` is array than get it using

```
type.getJSONArray("users");
```

**EDIT**

you can't make `for` loop on `JSONObject` you can get its value like this

```
users.getString("19x1");
```

**EDIT**

replace your `if` with this

```
if (own_name.equals("owner")) {
    JSONObject users = type.getJSONObject("users");
    Log.i("users", ":" + users);
    Iterator<String> keys = users.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        String value1;
        try {
            value1 = user.getString(key);
            userList.add(new Users(key, value1));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Users> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Users>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, userList);
    spinneraccountManager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: user is not array it is an object

Comment: I've edited answer, replace your if condition with this code

Answer (score 0):

Remove that for loop, for JSONObject you can not use for loop.
try using following code.

```
Iterator<String> iter = users.keys();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                String key = iter.next();
                try {
                    String value = users.getString(key);
                    Log.e("user",key+" "+value);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // Something went wrong!
                }
            }
```